# Sessions in Zappa (node.js)

Tags: session, node.js, express, zappa

What is the proper way to sessions enabled with Zappa?

The Zappa Crash Course implies that I need to merely `@use 'cookies', session: {secret: 'asdf'}` but this is not exporting `@request.session` -- Am I missing something? My call to console.log below results in `undefined` being printed.

```
require('zappa') '0.0.0.0', '8080', ->

  @use 'bodyParser',
       'methodOverride',
       @app.router,
       'static',
       'cookies',
       'cookieParser',
       session: {secret: '5465hfgh3t4grf'}

  @configure
    development: => @use errorHandler: {dumpExceptions: on}
    production: => @use 'errorHandler'

  @get '/': -> 
    console.log( @request.session )
    @render 'index.eco', {loginkey: @request.sessionID}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the `session` middleware above your routes:

```
require('zappa') '0.0.0.0', '8080', ->

  @use 'bodyParser',
       'methodOverride',
       'cookies',
       'cookieParser',
       session: {secret: '5465hfgh3t4grf'},
       @app.router,
       'static'

  @configure
    development: => @use errorHandler: {dumpExceptions: on}
    production: => @use 'errorHandler'

  @get '/': -> 
    console.log( @request.session )
    @render 'index.eco', {loginkey: @request.sessionID}
```

Otherwise, you won't have `session` on the request until after your route has executed, so to speak...

**Update:** Also note that, like other properties on `request` in zappa, `session` is copied to `this`, so you can access `@session` directly. There is also no `sessionId` on `request`, but there is a `@session.id`, you might want the route below instead:

```
@get '/': -> 
  console.log( @session )
  @render 'index.eco', {loginkey: @session.id}
```